# How to specify client IP for WebRequest and socket connection

Tags: c#, sockets

all

I have a box with multiple IP addresses, and I want my program to simulate multiple clients each with its own IP in one process on the box. For each specific client I need to choose an IP for all the outgoing HttpWebReqeusts and socket connections, the question is how can I specify the client IP for HttpWebRequests and socket connections in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The only way to have multiple IP addresses is to have multiple network interfaces (which might work for 2-3 IPs, but gets silly when you need hundreds).

However, if your HTTP server depends on the client IP, you're doing it wrong, as simple as that. Many different computers can have the same client IP as far as your server is concerned (routers, proxies, ...).